# when I use pnpm, how to set symlink for all the directory which in my workspace, just like yarn do

Tags: node-modules, monorepo, pnpm

my project like this

```
my-project
│
├─ node_modules *
├─ packages
│  ├─ a
│  │  └─ package.json
│  └─ b
│     └─ package.json
├─ package.json
```

In a's and b's package.json, I set their name "@mono/a" and "@mono/b",

how can I get a symlink @mono in my project's node_modules(the *), I've created and edited the `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `@mono/a` to the dependencies of `@mono/b`, you can run:

```
pnpm --filter=@mono/b add @mono/a
```

Or alternatively, you can change directory to `packages/b` and run:

```
pnpm add @mono/a
```

It will add this to the `package.json` of `@mono/b`:

```json
{
  "name": "@mono/b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mono/a": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

You can read more about the pnpm workspace [here](https://pnpm.io/workspaces).